# Add a Calendar in SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I maybe tagged for not being too detailed in this post but, how do you create a calendar in SharePoint 365 or 2019?  I looked in Site Contents (or whatever it is on 365/2019) but I don't see how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select Settings , and then select Site contents.
2. Select + New, and then select App.
3. Select 'Calendar' app from the list of apps.

[image]

4. Type the desired name you for your calendar app and click on Create.

More details can be found in [this Microsoft Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-in-sharepoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083).

Comment: thanks, just found it.

Comment: Please mark as answer if it helped you :-)

Comment: will do, I still have 3 min till I can mark as solved.